# Count column B value_counts for same values in column A

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, functional-programming, data-science

For the input dataframe below, we want to create two columns, A_count and B_count.

There is an input variable called surrounding_row_num. I.E. for surrounding_row_num=2, we want to look 2 rows before and 2 rows after the current row, and count the number of occurrences of 'A' in the column 'Label', that has the same 'ID' as the current row.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],'Label': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']})
    
   ID Label
0   1     A
1   1     A
2   1     B
3   1     B
4   2     A
5   2     B
```

Output for surrounding_row_num=2:

```
        ID  Label A_count B_count 
        1   A     2        1
        1   A     2        1
        1   B     1        2
        1   B     0        2        
        2   A     1        1
        2   B     1        1
```

Thanks!

Comment: your output for ID = 1 and Label = 'B' is not correct, for the first B there are two A within 2 spaces and for the second B there is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to account from ID groups:

```
df.set_index([df['ID'], 'Label'], append=True)['ID'].unstack()\
  .groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False)\
  .rolling(3, center=True).count()
```

Output:

```
Label    A    B
  ID           
0 1    2.0  0.0
1 1    2.0  1.0
2 1    1.0  2.0
3 1    0.0  2.0
4 2    1.0  1.0
5 2    1.0  1.0
```

---

Try this:

```
df.set_index('Label', append=True)['ID'].unstack().rolling(3, center=True).count()
```

Output:

```
Label    A    B
0      2.0  0.0
1      2.0  1.0
2      1.0  2.0
3      1.0  2.0
4      1.0  2.0
5      1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thats amazing Scott. You are great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually Scott this solution is great but it doesn't separate when the ID changes values. If a row has ID = 1, and the next row has ID=2, it still will look at the next row for the rolling count. Do you have a suggestion for that? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.  Yes, I do.  Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: That's great Scott. Thank you so much! How are you so good man? Is there like a pandas class or something to get better at pandas? Thanks again!

Comment: boPeng Yes.  There is.  I recommend @TedPetrou  [dunderdata](https://www.dunderdata.com/master-data-analysis-with-python?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dunderdata.com%2Fa%2F16370%2FzKnskk2y).